# How do I show a new column with values in sql select query?

Tags: sql, oracle

There is no primary key in the table.

My table is like

```
col1   col2   col3
12     34     35
56     34     35
13     56     35
56     34     35
12     56     34
```

I want a query which displays an extra column like this :

```
col0   col1   col2   col3
rox    12     34     35
max    56     34     35
bill   13     56     35
rox    56     34     35
sam    12     56     34
```

Comment: Where are values in the extra column coming from?

Comment: And why don't you?

Comment: So given your table has "no primary key" what is the relationship between value in `col0` and the existing columns?

Answer (score 0):

To add a new column

```
alter table your_table
     add col0 varchar2(10);
```

> "There is no primary key in the table."

So that means means the relationship between value in col0 and the existing columns is essentially random, which gives us a free hand in populating the new column.

Here is the test data:

```
SQL> select * from your_table;

COL0             COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
                   12         34         35
                   56         34         35
                   13         56         35
                   56         34         35
                   12         56         34

SQL>
```

Here is a PL/SQL routine which uses bulk operations to update all the rows in the table.

```
SQL> declare
  2      -- this collection type will be available in all Oracle databases
  3      new_col sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll :=
  4         sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('rox','max','bil','rox','sam');
  5      your_table_rowids sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll;
  6  begin
  7    -- note: solution fits given data, so does not bother to handle large volumnes
  8    select rowidtochar(yt.rowid)
  9    bulk collect into your_table_rowids
 10    from your_table yt;
 11
 12    -- NB: this is not a loop, this is a bulk operation
 13    forall idx in your_table_rowids.first()..your_table_rowids.last()
 14       update your_table yt
 15           set yt.col0 = new_col(idx)
 16           where yt.rowid = chartorowid(your_table_rowids(idx))
 17    ;
 18  end;
 19  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The nonsense with `ROWID` is necessary because your table has no primary key and duplicate rows.

Anyway, here's the outcome:

```
SQL> select * from your_table
  2  /

COL0             COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
rox                12         34         35
max                56         34         35
bil                13         56         35
rox                56         34         35
sam                12         56         34

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having [written an answer which uses DDL and UPDATE to change the database state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43405804/146325) I read the question title properly 8-) So here is a query which selects a pseudo-column `COL0`.

With this the test data:

```
SQL> select * from your_table
  2  /

      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
        12         34         35
        56         34         35
        13         56         35
        56         34         35
        12         56         34

SQL> with nt as (
  2      select column_value as col0
  3                , rownum as rn
  4     from
  5      table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('rox','max','bil','rox','sam'))
  6  )
  7  select nt.col0
  8             , yt.col1
  9             , yt.col2
 10             , yt.col3
 11  from nt
 12      join ( select t.*
 13                   , rownum as rn
 14           from your_table t) yt
 15      on yt.rn = nt.rn 
 16  /

COL0             COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
rox                12         34         35
max                56         34         35
bil                13         56         35
rox                56         34         35
sam                12         56         34

SQL>
```